# ajax AutoCompleteExtender not working

Tags: c#, asp.net

i have used AutoCompleteExtender, and created a web service but its not working, Code is as below

and web service code is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

public class AutoCompleteState : System.Web.Services.WebService {


ConnectionClass con = new ConnectionClass();
[WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
public string[] getStateList(string prefixText)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter adp=new SqlDataAdapter("Select distinct State from OPDPatients      where State Like '%" + prefixText+ "%' ",con.con);
    adp.Fill(dt);
    adp.Dispose();
    con.closeConnection();
    string[] setvalues=new  string[dt.Rows.Count];
    int i=0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        setvalues.SetValue(dr[0].ToString(), i);
        i++;
    }
    return setvalues;
}
```

}

i m not able to find error. Plz help

Comment: is the webservice called? Can you put a breakpoint on getSatetList() and see it called?

Comment: Your web service seems to be right, can you please paste the html side of the AutoCompleteExtender just to check if the attributes is set right.

Answer (score 0):

Please look at this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1581154.aspx/1) , i have similar type of problem before with autocompleteextender.

You have to check each & every parameter very carefully and also you have to take hidden field to store value if needed in your case.

Let me know about your result.